# xmlHttpRequest to get json file from project folder

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." always shows this whenever i tried to get json file through xmlHttpResuest. I have my  project on
my hard disk. There is a .json file at the same folder where html,js,css files are. I run this project directly from the server. I need to get the json file from that html page using xmlHttpRequest. I can not use any local server.

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
        callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
}


readTextFile("Game/test.json", function(text){
var data = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(data);
```

});

Comment: Could you please add a snapshot of the error from the console?

Comment: The description is clear enough, you can't use XMLHttpRequest if you don't have any server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code as code editor consider installing extension called live-server and start/run your application on this server. It support file changes detection and CORS enabled.